# VSCode cannot find modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, openai-api

I have tried so many things here is the error I am getting, I am on Windows 11

I am also having this error for module google on another file for this same project, but I figure one step at a time, unless I need to do something there also.

What I have tried:

1. Fully uninstalling and reinstalling vscode
2. pip uninstall openai, pip install --upgrade pip, pip install openai, pip list pip to make sure it is there (also all of these for pip3
3. Gone into system properties and added all paths that have been shown to me to path
4. Checked my python version both in vscode and in the windows powershell, they match
5. Uninstalled all python from my system and reinstalled only python 3.10 and repeated all steps above to make sure it is correct
6. Simply restarted vscode to make sure it was not a temporary error

```
import openai
import os

openai.api_key = 'Taken out for obvious reasons'

def get_completion(prompt, model="gpt-3.5-turbo"):
    messages = [{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model=model,
        messages=messages,
        temperature=0,  # this is the degree of randomness of the model's output
    )
    return response.choices[0].message["content"]


prompt = f"""
Hi, what's 10+10?
"""
response = get_completion(prompt)
print(response)
```

result:

```
File "d:/Homework/OU/Fall 2023/SoftEng/Group5/Repo/CSI3370/OpenAISetup.py", line 1, in <module>
    import openai
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai'
```

*Edited to add the output of commands that were asked:

```
pip show openai

Name: openai
Version: 0.28.1
Summary: Python client library for the OpenAI API
Home-page: https://github.com/openai/openai-python
Author: OpenAI
Author-email: support@openai.com
License: 
Location: c:\users\mike\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages
Requires: aiohttp, requests, tqdm
Required-by:

import sys; print(sys.path)

PS D:\Homework\OU\Fall 2023\SoftEng\Group5\Repo\CSI3370> & C:/Users/Mike/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe "d:/Homework/OU/Fall 2023/SoftEng/Group5/Repo/CSI3370/DebugFile.py"
['d:\\Homework\\OU\\Fall 2023\\SoftEng\\Group5\\Repo\\CSI3370', 'C:\\Users\\Mike\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Mike\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Mike\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Mike\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310', 'C:\\Users\\Mike\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages']

Get-Command pip

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     pip.exe                                            0.0.0.0    C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows... 


$Env:Path

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Mike\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts;C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts
```

Comment: Show us the output of this command `pip show openai`, especially the `Location:` line, and also the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: And please include those in the question, not in a comment.

Comment: I edited the post for the pip command, but wanted to clarify do you want the path which the import sys code gives or something else, since it just opens a folder, and if you want the path do you just want me to add that to the post?

Comment: I want the output of that `print()` statement, when you run it in vscode.  I don't know what you mean by "it just opens a folder".  Make a new py script file that only has that one line, and run it in vs code.

Comment: When I run the code you gave me, it simply opens my file explorer. When I close that I get an output which I have put in the post

Comment: The filename is `Untitled-1`, so it seems that you did not save the file??

Comment: I misunderstood as I'm scouring the internet while talking about this, the updated code has been posted (the folder opening was asking me to save the file apparently). I named it DebugFile.py

Comment: Okay, the problem is as I suspected.  You have two separate installations of python on your computer.  One is in `c:\users\mike\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310`, and the other is in `C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310`.

Comment: I don't understand how that could've happened but this is a new thread for me to pull. How do I proceed to fix this?

Comment: I would start by investigating why the `pip` command is using the first installation.  Can you show the output of this command `which pip`

Comment: If it were me, I would probably just remove that first installation.  But I don't know how your computer is set up, so that may not be completely safe.

Comment: which pip gives me a lot of red text saying 'which' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: I guess I'm too used to a unix environment.  Are you using powershell?  If you are, you can use this `Get-Command pip`  If not, I think this will work `where pip.exe`

Comment: Yes I am using powershell, I should have mentioned that earlier. I have added the output to the post

Comment: Well, that output points to yet a third location `C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows...` which is very confusing.

Comment: In general, the right way to solve this problem is to decide which installation of python you want to use, and then configure your environment so that all your tools agree on that installation.  And ideally **remove** the others, although that may or may not be possible depending on your specific setup.

Comment: The immediate problem is that your `pip` command is using a different installation of python than your vs code is using.

Comment: See this is starting to make more sense why I couldn't solve this from just looking things up. Do I need to fresh install everything again following certain steps to make sure this does not happen again? How do I remedy any of this?

Comment: Can you show the value of your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: is there a command I can put in the powershell to have it output in the terminal? I have a screenshot from my windows settings of it if not

Comment: This command should work `$Env:Path`

Comment: Original post has been updated with the output

Comment: I think the solution is to use the `pip.exe` in `C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts`, instead of the one it is using right now.  Can you edit your `PATH` variable, and move `C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts` to be earlier in the sequence so that it finds that one first?

Comment: So in my 'Edit environment variable' window it is now the top of the 5 that are in there

Comment: This is now giving the correct answer, thank you very much. Do you recommend anything else to prevent this from happening again? Or just leave it as is

Comment: The root cause was probably as you mentioned in a response to the other answer, that you "reinstalled" Python 3.10, except it wasn't actually a reinstall, it was a **separate** brand-new installation that ended up conflicting with the existing installation you already had.

Comment: And as I mentioned earlier, I think the best solution would be to remove the installation in `c:\users\mike\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0`.  Although I'm curious why you even installed this one in the first place, as you clearly already had Python 3.10 installed in another location?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem multiple times. Press `Shift + Ctrl + P` and then click on `Python: Select Interpreter` and then select a different interprter.

Comment: I have done that and get the same "No module named 'openai'", this is what prompted me to uninstall everything including all python versions and reinstall only python 3.10 which is what my group has been working with this on